# Unit Testing for Extendscript

Tags: unit-testing, gruntjs, mocha.js, extendscript, photoshop-script

Need some guidance on automating unit testing for Extendscript..anyone have any experience running and writing unit tests on Adobe Extendscript jsx files with Grunt, Mocha, Chai, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested by using

- [substack/tape: tap-producing test harness for node and browsers](https://github.com/substack/tape)
- [nbqx/estktap: tap(tape) wrapper for testing adobe extendscript](https://github.com/nbqx/estktap)

in my script.

here is an example.

https://github.com/milligramme/scriptui_boilerplate/blob/master/ui/test/test.js

not automating, but it will be easy to set in gulp workflow.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had the same need. I've updated [jasminejsx](https://github.com/theasci/jasminejsx) for testing in ExtendScript using Jasmine.js (2.5) and a custom Logger *without* the need of ExtendScript Toolkit.

I use an adaptation in my [cep-bootstrap project](https://github.com/theasci/cep-bootstrap) but I plan to update it soon with the newest jasminejsx.